# Canvas fillText at y 0 will cutoff square brackets

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I want to have a text at the very bottom of the canvas, so I do:

```
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.width);
```

That works nice for every type of char but square brackets are cut off at the bottom:

Large text:

[image: large text]

Small text:

[image: small text]

One solution would be to just set the y value to `canvas.width - someSpacing` but there is a different count of pixels cutoff at the small and big text.

So is there a way that the brackets aren't cut off?

```js
var canvas =  document.getElementById("mycanvas");
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("[027722]", canvas.width, canvas.width)
ctx.font = "11px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillText("[027722]", 10, canvas.width)
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: How are you determining the height of the text? Please add a reproducable/working example of your code that clearly shows your issue.

Comment: No, I only set the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the **baseline** of fonts. In Typography this term is used to describe an imaginary ground where the text actually 'rests'.
The canvas API offers six different types of baselines.

[image]

As you might assume from the above, canvas defaults to 'alphabetic'.

Luckily the fix is simple - you just need to switch the baseline to either **bottom** or **ideographic**. This can be done by changing the `.textBaseline`  property accordingly.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("[027722]", canvas.width, canvas.height)
ctx.font = "11px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillText("[027722]", 10, canvas.height)
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="background: #f9f9f9">
```